# The condition in conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm given the statement:

"A survey of Australians living outside of Melbourne or Sydney has found that 25% have not visited Melbourne, 15% have not visited Sydney, and 10% have never been to Sydney or Melbourne, A person is selected at random."

with the following questions:

*a) If she has not visited Melbourne, what is the probability that she has not visited Sydney?*

*b) If she has not visited Sydney, what is the probability that she has not visited Melbourne?*

The answers provided are as follows:

Probability of Not Visiting Melbourne = $P(M) = 0.25$

Probability of Not Visiting Sydney = $P(S) = 0.15$

$P(M \cap S)$ = 0.10

I'm wondering why we are using an intersection here, as the question says "never been to Sydney **or** Melbourne", and not "Sydney **and** Melbourne"?

Furthermore,

The answer for A has been given as:
a) "The probability that a person has not visited Melbourne given that she has not visited Sydney" = P(M|S) = ....

b) "The probability that a person has not visited Sydney given that she has not visited Melbourne" = P(S|M) = ...

Now, I'm having trouble seeing how a) is the answer for a), and b) is the answer for b). In my eyes, they should be the other way around...

Here's why:

a) "**If she has not visited Melbourne**, what is the probability she has not visited Sydney?
b) **If she has not visited Sydney** what is the probability she has not visited Melbourne?

In my eyes, the condition is what immediately follows the "if". Yet, for a) the condition is NOT what follows the if, and for b), the condition is NOT what follows the if.

So, I don't know if this is a mistake on their part, or if I am confused in what the condition is in Conditional Probability...

Can anyone please help me with resolving this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question (the use of the intersection rather than the union of the events $M$ and $S$), this is an instance of one of De Morgan's laws. The event 'the selected person has never been to Sydney or Melbourne' means that it is not true that she has ever been to either of the cities Sydney or Melbourne. In other words, she has not been to Sydney, nor has she been to Melbourne. Symbolically, we write $(M^c \cup S^c)^c = M \cap S$. Here, the superscript $^c$ is used to denote the complementary of the respective event.

Regarding the second part of your question, you are right, the answers have been mixed up.

Comment: I see, I did use Demorgans to come to that conclusion earlier but with their allocations of M and S: M = "Not visiting Melbourne", S = "Not visiting Sydney", It seems that to apply demorgans here, M would need to be "HAS visited Melbourne" and S would need to be "HAS visited Sydney", thus $(M \cup S)^\complement$ = $M^\complement \cap S^\complement$, So it would really be $P(M^\complement \cap S^\complement)$ - wouldn't it?

Comment: I just adhered to the notation you used in your question. You can apply De Morgan's law to any pair of events you like. Just write it down first using some other set of variables, say $X$ and $Y$ in the form you would find in a textbook, $(X \cup Y)^C = X^C \cap Y^C$, then substitute $M^C$ for $X$ and $S^C$ for $Y$, and take into account that $(M^C)^C = M$ and $(S^C)^C = S$.

Comment: indeed, but they have assigned M to "Not Visited Melbourne" and S to "Not Visited Sydney", so there is no complement that we can work with, as M^c would equal "Not Not Visiting Melbourne" = "Visiting Melbourne", which would make our final expression "Visiting Melbourne or Sydney", which doesn't have a complement in it at all?

Comment: The complement of the event in the parentheses is still there (it stays for the 'not' in 'NOT having visited Melbourne or Sydney'). We get rid of it by applying De Morgan's law.

Comment: Then why do we substitute M^c for X, instead of just M for X as We would be substituting NOT "not visited melbourne" - That complement doesn't exist in the first place, Essentially We're saying M^c = M by doing that, I can't see how that is allowed in practice?

Comment: The idea is that $X$ means 'she has visited Melbourne', while $Y$ means 'she has visited Sydney'. Thus, the event 'she has not visited Melbourne or Sydney', or in other words, 'it is not the case that she has visited Melbourne or that she has visited Sydney', is given by the expression $(X \cup Y)^C$. Applying De Morgan's law to this statement, we obtain $X^C \cap Y^C$, that is 'she has not visited Melbourne and she has not visited Sydney'. With the conventions of your original post, this can also be expressed as $M \cap S$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I understand the question correctly, 'never been to Sydney or Melbourne' is event $S \cap M$. Your first question asks for $P(S|M)$, the second $P(M|S)$. Now keep in mind two things:

1) $P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A)$

2) $P(A \cap B) = P(B |A)P(A)$

Comment: Okay, is it a mistake then, their answer for a) is really the answer for b), and their answer for b) is really the answer for a)?

Also, I suppose to conform to the conditional probability formula we need to use "and", but in their textual description, they use "or". The event $S \cap M$ = Never been to Sydney and Melbourne =/= $S \cup M$ = Never been to Sydney or Melbourne.

Can you elaborate on why we use intersect - when the question contains the word "or"? It is just a given that in any question like this one should assume they mean "and"?

Comment: OK, then maybe my reading is wrong and what you need is $P(M \cap S) = P(M) + P(S) - P(M \cup S)$, where $P(M \cup S)$ is $0.1$. But then the suggestions in my answer are still valid.

Answer (score 0):

"10% have never been to Sydney or Melbourne"
means 10 % have neither been to Sydney nor Melbourne.
Also, the other interpretation (you provided) would violate this $n(M \cup S) = n(M) + n(S) - n(M \cap S) $, with $n(M) = 0.25, n(S) = 0.15$. Obviously, $n(M \cup S)$ has to be greater than or equal to $n(M)$.
Given this I think the rest of questions are substitution problems.